# How can I add additional inputs above my DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables.js. Everything works as I want, but I would like for the "from" and to" boxes to be in between the excel download button and the search bar, and I would like them to look the same as the search bar. I can't figure out how to make them inline and go there... this is my datatable code:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var newRequestTable = $('#newRequestTable').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [{ extend: 'excelHtml5', text: 'Download as Excel file' }]
        });
```

I'm not really sure how to get in between the "Bfrtip" section. Is it possible to rearrange things a bit? I am so awful at arranging things on pages.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is more so dealing with datatable's api than it is rearranging things on a page. Here's an example to get you going as I know this was difficult for me starting out. (view full page)

The main portion is using the 'dom' option, which allows you to modify the row you're talking about, but it uses a custom string to parse and create id's and classes, while adding something like the search box using `f`. 
See https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var dataSet = [
    ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
    ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"],
    ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
    ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"],
    ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
    ["Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000"],
    ["Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500"],
    ["Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900"],
    ["Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500"],
    ["Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600"],
    ["Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560"],
    ["Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000"],
    ["Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600"],
    ["Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500"],
    ["Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750"],
    ["Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500"],
    ["Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000"],
    ["Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500"],
    ["Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000"],
    ["Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500"],
    ["Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000"],
    ["Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000"],
    ["Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450"],
    ["Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sidney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600"],
    ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
    ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
    ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
    ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
    ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
    ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
    ["Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sidney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400"],
    ["Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500"],
    ["Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000"],
    ["Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500"],
    ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
    ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
  ];

  var columnDefs = [{
    title: "Name"
  }, {
    title: "Position"
  }, {
    title: "Office"
  }, {
    title: "Extn."
  }, {
    title: "Start date"
  }, {
    title: "Salary"
  }];

  var myTable;

  myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    data: dataSet,
    columns: columnDefs,
  dom: "<'row'<'mySelector col-sm-2'l><'myButtons col-sm-2'b><'myInput1 col-sm-3'b><'myInput2 col-sm-3'><'col-sm-2 searchControl'f>><'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-12'p>>",
    buttons: [{ name:'add', text: '<b>Download Excel</b>' }],
    select: 'single',
    responsive: true
  });
  myTable.buttons().container().appendTo( '.myButtons' );
  $('.mySelector').prepend(`<label for="add">&nbsp;</label>`);
  $('.myButtons .dt-buttons').prepend(`<label for="add">&nbsp;</label>`);
  $('.myInput1').append(`<label for="basic-url">Input 1</label>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
</div>`)
  $('.myInput2').append(`<label for="basic2">Input 2</label>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic2" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
</div>`)
  $('.searchControl').append($('.searchControl input').detach())
  $('.searchControl input').addClass('form-control')

});
```

```css
table.dataTable tbody>tr.selected,
table.dataTable tbody>tr>.selected {
  background-color: #A2D3F6;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/css/select.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.2/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.2/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable table table-striped" id="example">

  </table>
</div>
```